# Two values for one int

Tags: c, int

I want to put two values for int x and two for int y. This code will actually run perfectly, but I get two warnings when compiling because I'm not using one of the values for each int. Is there a better way to do this or should I just ignore the warning?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()  {
int x = (10, 20);
int y = (15, 25);

if (x > y)
{
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
else if (y > x)
{
    printf("%d\n", y);
}
else {
    printf("Both values are the same.\n");
}}
```

Warning message:

```
compare_vars.c:4:11: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    int x = (10, 20);
             ^~
compare_vars.c:5:11: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    int y = (15, 25);
             ^~
```

2 warnings generated.

(Edit: Turned out my teacher only wanted one value for each variable. I did however learn a lot from this confusing Q/A. Next assignment will probably contain arrays wich I feel comfterble about now :-);)

Comment: You cannot put two feet in one shoe! Also you cannot put two values in one variable.

Comment: Wait wait wait, it doesn't compile but it runs?

Comment: please add your compilation error, it can be useful for helping you understand the problem

Comment: @ChemiCalChems It is probably just a warning.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I'm starting to think so.

Comment: That's really a warning   . It can be hard to tell with gcc and clang since the word "warning" is used for both warnings and errors

Comment: "should I just ignore the warning" --> after one had coded for 10 years maybe, else no.

Comment: Even after 10 years, no. *You* might know a certain warning is safe to ignore. The next person doesn't. Make sure your code compiles without warnings.

Answer (score 4):

`int x` declares a variable `x` of type `int`. **One** int.

What you are looking for is a *pair* of `int`, a data type that does not exist natively in C. (*)

You can use arrays...

```
int x[2] = { 10, 20 };
```

...or structs...

```
struct int_pair
{
    int first;
    int second;
} x;

struct int_pair x = { 10, 20 };
```

...but you would have to write your own compare function, as the operator `>` won't do for either case.

---

(*):  Look to e.g. pmg's or Bathsheba's answer as to why initializing a single `int` with what looks like a pair of `int` to you does not yield a compiler error.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'll go with arrays ;)

Comment: @CasperT.: I'd happily written up an example compare function for you, but it was not clear what your definition of "larger than" would be for e.g. `(10, 20)` and `(15, 15)`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`(10, 20);` is an *expression* equal to 20. (That's how the *comma* operator works: it evaluates all the arguments and the value of the expression equals the final term).

So your code is valid (hence successful compilation), but it does contain redundant data.

Did you want `int x[] = {10, 20};` etc. instead? i.e. create an *array* with two elements, and *access* the elements using code like `x[0]` and `x[1]` &c. Note that `x > y` would then be *undefined* since you'd be comparing *pointers* (the address of the first element in each of the two arrays) that are not part of the same array.

Comment: `x > y` would not work as intended with the array

Comment: @M.M: It wouldn't work with the `struct` either.

Comment: @M.M. It's worse than that: the compiler might eat your cat.

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator yields the value to the right.

The expression

```
4, 3
```

has the value `3`.

What you are doing is assigning a single value to each variable.

---

If your values are small enough, you may codify the values. For example, if all the values are less than `1000`

```
x = 42003; // 42 and 3
y = 538907; // 538 and 907

if (x % 1000 == y / 1000) /* if 3 == 538 */;
```

---

Or you could use arrays!

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this approach. Upvoted.

Comment: `x > y` would be sufficient too, to act like `tie` for the comparison. Watch out for leading `0` octal constants though...

Comment: "... if all the values are less than 1000" --> assumes `int` is wider than the C spec min of 16-bit.  "less than 100" would make more sense.  16-bit is very common in 2016 in embedded processors.